# Skype for Business window resizes and shrinks itself erratically

Tags: windows-10, skype, window

When I have a conversation window open containing multiple conversations, and I snap it to half the screen using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> (or by simply dragging it to the left edge of the screen), it resizes and positions itself appropriately.

But when I select another conversation from the left-hand sidebar, the window breaks completely from its size/position, and jumps to another size/position on the screen altogether.

Further, when I switch back and forth between conversations, the window decrements its own width by a couple hundred pixels or so until it can narrow itself no more and the conversations themselves are hardly visible.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Notes:
OS: Windows 10 x64

Comment: I'd wonder if you don't have some sort of hotkey-based window management utility running. Things to check first: Update your video drivers, make sure you've got the latest patches for Office (these should update Skype for Business too), and check for an disable any utilities running on your computer that manage window sizes.

Comment: Same issue. I can confirm that I have no 3rd party window management utilities installed and the problem only occurs with Skype for Business and with no other apps. Skype version #16.0.7726.1049 32 bit. Restarting Skype does appear to temporarily resolve the issue. I suspect it's a bug in Skype.

Comment: Can confirm what Thomas said back in August. This is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might relate to the Windows 10 window management that e.g. snaps window to cover half a screen automatically. I encountered this problem when I changed from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

I managed to circumvent the problem by manually locating and sizing the Skype and chat windows to the preferred location. The procedure is as follows:

1. Manually (not using any window management snap functions etc.) locate and size Skype window to the preferred location on the screen. Exit
   Skype completely. Reopen and adjust the location to the preferred
   position again. Repeat until the window keeps in the preferred location.
2. Do the same thing for the chat window. Manually (not using any window management snap functions etc.) locate and size to the preferred location. Close the chat window and reopen it. Repeat until the chat window keeps its location and size.

I had to do two to three iterations to "teach" Skype the window positions.

This is merely a workaround and I guess you have to repeat the process every time you want to change the Skype or chat window location. I'd like to have a fix to the Skype functionality instead.